# Is the file lock necessary for bash `tee -a`

Tags: bash, logging, tee, flock

I use `tee -a` to log data from multiple processes to the one file. I haven't found any example of using `flock` with `tee -a`

1. Should I use in this case `flock` to prevent the log file from being corrupted?
2. How should I use `tee -a` with `flock`?
3. Should I remove flock manually or it will be removed automatically?